# Is there a more simple way to convert a string of sequence of numbers to a list in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have this string x = "1-3,5,7,11-16,20"
and I want to transform it to a list of integers like this:

[1,2,3,5,7,11,12,13,14,15,16,20].

I wrote this code and it does work:

```
def page_range(x):
    p = x.split(',')
    d = list()
    nums = list()
    for i in range(0,len(p)):
        d.append(p[i].find('-'))

    for i in range(0,len(d)):
        if d[i] >= 1:
            z,y = p[i].split('-')
            nums = nums + list(range(int(z),int(y)+1))
        else:
            nums.append(int(p[i]))
    return nums
```

But is there a more simple way to do that?

Comment: Output is a list of strings or list of Integers?

Comment: list of integers, I updated the question

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach

```
x = "1-3,5,7,11-16,20"
res = []
for i in x.split(","):
    if "-" in i:
        s, e = i.split("-")
        res.extend(range(int(s), int(e)+1))
    else:
        res.append(int(i))
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 20]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is simpler if you define a function to convert a string like `12` or `4-5` into the numbers it represents:

```py
def str_to_nums(s):
    if '-' in s:
        a, b = map(int, s.split('-'))
        return range(a, b+1)
    else:
        return int(s), # comma makes this a one-element tuple
```

Then you can use a list comprehension:

```py
>>> [n for s in x.split(',') for n in str_to_nums(s)]
[1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 20]
```

Answer (score 0):

This could also be tried:

```
ls = []
for i in x.split(','):
    if i.isdigit() != 1:
        r1, r2 = i.split('-')
        ls.extend(range(int(r1), int(r2)+1))
    else:
        ls.append(int(i))
```